# Manejo de nulos en Scala

Tags: nullpointerexception, scala

Estoy tratando de usar la clase `Option` para evitar un `NullPointerException` que surge en la siguiente línea:

```
} else Task(file.getText, file.getVirtualFile.getParent.getPath, new SwiPrologLinter(toolchain))
```

### Intentos

tras ver que `Option` no me servía, traté de llamar al método fábrica de `Option` y luego un `flatmap`

```
else{
  val optionalFile=Option(file)
  if(optionalFile.isEmpty) Abort() else Task(optionalFile.map(_.getText).getOrElse(""), optionalFile.flatMap(x=>Option(x.getVirtualFile)).map(_.getParent).map(_.getPath).getOrElse(""), new SwiPrologLinter(toolchain))
}
```

A pesar de ello la traza es la siguiente:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile.getPath()" because "x$3" is null
    at tech.phosphorus.intellij.prolog.annotator.PrologExternalAnnotator$$anonfun$collectInformation$5.apply(external-annotator.scala:46)
    at tech.phosphorus.intellij.prolog.annotator.PrologExternalAnnotator$$anonfun$collectInformation$5.apply(external-annotator.scala:46)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at tech.phosphorus.intellij.prolog.annotator.PrologExternalAnnotator.collectInformation(external-annotator.scala:46)
    at tech.phosphorus.intellij.prolog.annotator.PrologExternalAnnotator.collectInformation(external-annotator.scala:26)
    at com.intellij.lang.annotation.ExternalAnnotator.collectInformation(ExternalAnnotator.java:60)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ExternalToolPass.collectInformationWithProgress(ExternalToolPass.java:135)
    ... 21 more
```

Alguna idea de como puedo evitar ese NPE?

Comment: Ese `null` no es de scala, sino de la librería java que estás usando. Tú código debe considerarlo como una _excepción_ (o sea, usando sentencias `try..catch...`, preventivamente comprobando que no sea `null`, o con el funcional `Try/Success/Failure`). En la documentación vienen algunos ejemplos: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/fp-functional-error-handling.html

Comment: lo corregí con validaciones de nulos nivel extremo sin necesidad de usar try catch

Answer (score 1):

No termino de entender bien cuál es la instancia que tenés en null. Incluso cómo queda ordenado el código es medio difícil de leer. Tal vez podrías hacer algo así

```
for {
  f <- Option(file)
  text <- Option(f.getText)
  virtualFile <- Option(f.getVirtualFile)
  parent <- Option(virtualFile.getParent)
  path <- Option(parent.getPath)
} yield Task(param1, param2, param3...)
```

el [for yield / for comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) en scala, es un syntax sugar de los métodos map, flatMap y filter para evitar tener que hacer esas llamadas de forma manual que no quedan muy legibles una vez q te acosumbras a leerlo de la forma que lo ejemplifiqué.

Otra cosa tmb a tener en cuenta, es que la idea del `Option` no es consultarle si tiene o no tiene algo para luego extraer su valor, sería lo mismo que estar haciendo un null check clásico de java. La idea es usar map, flatMap o filter y despreocuparte si tiene o no tiene un valor null.

Todo esto viene de algo llamado `Monad`, que cuando uno intenta leer la documentación por primera vez aparecen montones de nombres y teorías confusas que en un principio mucho no ayudan a entenderlo. Intentando verlo de una forma medianamente simple sin entrar en mucho detalle, para el `Option` tenés como el caso feliz (`Some`) y el caso no feliz (`None`). Cada vez que llames a map o flatMap, vas a estar retornando un nuevo `Option`. En el caso de `map`, si tenés un `Some`,  devolvés un nuevo `Some` con el valor interno transformado, mientras que si tenías un `None` devolvés nuevamente un `None`. Para el `flatMap`, tiene que la transformación que le apliques, va a ser un `Option` lo que tenés como valor de retorno en la función que pasás por parámetro. Esto va a hacer que tu `Option` pueda convertirse en un nuevo `Some` o `None` (cosa que con el map sólo podías obtener un nuevo Some), y en el caso que tuvieras un `None`, vas a volver a retornar nuevamente un `None`.

Habiendo comprendido la explicación dada en el párrafo anterior, si revisamos el código que dejé de ejemplo más arriba, vas a tener que si en el medio de alguno de esos `flatMap`s aplicados, alguno te retorna `None`, todo lo que sigue para abajo no se va a ejecutar y vas a obtener un `None`, pudiendo aplicar ahora sí un simple `getOrElse(Abort())`. De esta forma, si tenías ya un `Some(Task(...))`, a través del `getOrElse` vas a obtener ese `Some` y sino te va a retornar el `Abort()` que le pasaste como parámetro

Comment: El problema con `Option` es que no te evita las excepciones. Si quieres una orientación _funcional_ (*monads*) lo apropiado es encapsular la expresión en un `Try` y transformarlo luego en otras monads como `Option` o `Either`. Por ejemplo, `Try(1/0).toOption` vendría a ser una excepción convertida en un `Option[Int]` (en este caso, `None`), con lo que puedes usarla tal como dices en un for o con otras transformaciones monádicas.

Comment: @ChemaCortes totalmente de acuerdo. Es algo a tener en consideración cuando se usan cosas hechas en java